# Rails - Render views common to specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

Hi I've been fiddling with this for the last few hours and am unsure how to solve and what's the best practice for doing it.

I have 2 types of content views. One with a single column for most of the application and another with two columns that I want to use for 3 specific controllers.

Here's what I have so far:

> **app/views/layouts/_content.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user&&current_page?(controller: companies) %>

<div class="bevel-container"> 

    <div class="row">

        <div id="left_navbar" class="col-md-2">

        </div> 

        <div id="right_content" class="col-md-10"> 
                <p>The 2 column partial is showing</p>

                <%= yield %>

        </div> 

    </div>  

</div><


<% else %>

    <div class="container"> 

        <p>The single column partial is showing</p>
        <%= yield %>

    </div>

<% end %>
```

This isn't working. I thought I'd be able to define this view if the companies_controller is being used i.e. `<% if current_user&&current_page?(controller: companies) %>` but I keep getting the following:

> **Error**

```
undefined local variable or method `companies' for #<#<Class:0x00000004c2fe58>:0x00000005194a88>
```

In my **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** I have

```
<div> <!-- Outer Div -->

    <%= render 'layouts/top_nav' %> 

    <%= render 'layouts/content' %>     

</div><!-- Close Outer Div -->
```

I'm getting a bit stumped on how to solve this. I tried creating a file `app/views/layouts/_companies_html.erb` to handle the 2 column content views but I don't know what to change my application.html.erb to in order to render `_companies.html.erb` when the companies_controller is being used -> It means I'm back at `<% if current_user&&current_page?(controller: companies) %>`. Going around in circles here big time.

Can anyone explain best practice for this stuff and how I go about rendering a common layout for the companies controller as opposed to the common layout for the rest of the application?

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current logic would work if you change the `if` to something like this:

```
<% if current_user && controller_name == "companies" %>
```

As for best practices, you could have a layout that's specific to the companies controller by adding this to companies_controller.rb:

```
layout :companies
```